# why update ubuntu not over https protocol

Tags: updates

why by default Ubuntu updates doesn't uses HTTPS protocol?

is there any man-in-the-middle attack concerns at all?

sorry if this has been asked repeatedly already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The updates are digitally signed, and will be rejected if the signatures don't match. There is nothing a man in the middle can do, except maybe a denial of service, which they could also do with HTTPS.